# Pinax-theme-bootstrap editing

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, pinax

Pinax theme for Bootstrap on Django twitter lacks a clear guide. Like how it's supposed to send emails when you haven't specified the email_host and password. Changing the top bar to include other links like Home Contact etc.

I've tried to find the pages, other bootstrap themes from bootwatch also don't take effect. How do you change it?

Answer (score 0):

Email settings will be the same as django's

Example:-

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

# Host for sending e-mail.
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'

# Port for sending e-mail.
EMAIL_PORT = 1025

# Optional SMTP authentication information for EMAIL_HOST.
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

Or if you are using a remote mail server, something like this:-

```
EMAILS_ALLOWED = True
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'no-replymysite.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'myspecialpass'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[MySite.com]'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'MySite.com Auto Notification <no-reply@mysite.com>'
```

Regarding the 2nd question about changing the theme/look-and-feel, I have responded to a similar question here, just yesterday - [How to change the pinax(0.9a2) template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211233/how-to-change-the-pinax0-9a2-template/13211486#13211486)