# How do I load my custom CSS in pinax (Django))?

Tags: django, pinax

I want to try and overide the default bootstrap css files that I got with `pinax`, for example change the `topnav` background color and change the style of `<p class="a12" >gggggggg</p>` I created.
I saw that link in stakoverflow 
[How to change the pinax(0.9a2) template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211233/how-to-change-the-pinax0-9a2-template)

I added my custom css in mysite\static\css\my_custom_stuff.css
the css:

```
.a12{
 background-color: red;
 color: green;
}
.topbar-inner, .topbar .fill {
 background-color: red;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333, #FF4242);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333, #FF4242);
 background-image: linear-gradient(top, #333, #FF4242);
}
```

and added the folowing to the homepage.html

```
{% block extra_head %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/my_custom_stuff.css">
<p class="a12" >gggggggg</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Can someone please help me understand what am I doing wrong?
And how should I do it correct
Thanks in advance

Comment: When I added  "os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static"),"  to STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static", "dist"),
 os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static"),
I see the changes Itried  the folowing -> os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static","css"), as I wanted to be specific  and  it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

it works fine when I addded

```
os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static"),
```

to the STATICFILES_DIRS